# Prevent changing of approvers list in approval workflow in SharePoint 2010

Tags: workflow

In SharePoint 2007, the OOTB document approval workflow had an option “Allow changes to the participant list when this workflow is started”. This option has disappeared in the 2010 OOTB approval workflow, and it seems the approval list is *always* editable. Is it possible to set up an approval workflow in SharePoint 2010 where the approvers list cannot be changed at workflow initiation?